# C++ - Is this conditional statement written correctly? Or is there a more effective way to write it?

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, conditional-statements

I have a program that attempts to find a magic square. A square matrix of numbers where all the rows,columns,diagonals add up to the same number.

So far I have a 3x3 array that successfully populates with truly random numbers.  It appears to work properly in doing so, but when I include the program in a `while(true)` loop, the program runs on forever without finding the magic square, and I think it's because my conditional statement is written incorrectly. Here's it is:

```cpp
if (row0 == row1 == row2 == col0 == col1 == col2 == dia1 == dia2) {
    cout << "We have a magic square!" <<  endl;
    cout << troysArray[i][j];
    cout << "";
    break;
}
```

The whole program is here:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;
//Defining the sum function, which takes 3 integers as arguments.
int addnums(int x,int y,int z){
    int result = x + y + z;
    return result;}

int main() {
    srand(time(0));

//Initial array contents before random numbers are substituted
int troysArray[3][3] = {
{1,3,2},
{4,6,5},
{7,9,8},
};

int i;
int j;

int row0;
int zero_zero;
int zero_one;
int zero_two;

int row1;
int one_zero;
int one_one;
int one_two;

int row2;
int two_zero;
int two_one;
int two_two;

int col0;
int col1;
int col2;

int dia1;
int dia2;
int sum = row0;

while(true) {
for (i = 0;i < 3;i++){
    for (j = 0;j < 3;j++){
        //Generating random numbers between 1-9, with which to populate troysArray.
        troysArray[i][j] = 1 + (rand() % 9);
        cout << troysArray[i][j];
        cout << "";
    //If all the rows,columns, and diagonals are equal,we have a magic square!
    if (row1 == sum && row2 == sum && col0 == sum && col1 == sum && col2 == sum &&
        dia1 == sum && dia2 == sum) {
        cout << "We have a magic square!" << endl;
        cout << troysArray[i][j];
        cout << "";
        break;}
    }
    cout << endl;

}
}
//Adding up row 0 (top row):
zero_zero = troysArray[0][0];
zero_one = troysArray[0][1];
zero_two = troysArray[0][2];
row0 = addnums(zero_zero,zero_one,zero_two);
cout << "The sum of row 0 equals: " << zero_zero + zero_one + zero_two << endl;

//Adding up row 1 (middle row):
one_zero = troysArray[1][0];
one_one = troysArray[1][1];
one_two = troysArray[1][2];
row1 = addnums(one_zero,one_one,one_two);
cout << "The sum of row 1 equals: " << one_zero + one_one + one_two << endl;

//Adding up row 2 (bottom row):
two_zero = troysArray[2][0];
two_one = troysArray[2][1];
two_two = troysArray[2][2];
row2 = addnums(two_zero,two_one,two_two);
cout << "The sum of row 2 equals: " << two_zero + two_one + two_two << endl;

cout << "\n";

//Adding up col 0 (Left):
col0 = addnums(zero_zero,one_zero,two_zero);
cout << "The sum of col 0 equals: " << zero_zero + one_zero + two_zero << endl;

//Adding up col 1 (Middle):
col1 = addnums(zero_one,one_one,two_one);
cout << "The sum of col 1 equals: " << zero_one + one_one + two_one << endl;

//Adding up col 2 (Right):
col2 = addnums(zero_two,one_two,two_two);
cout << "The sum of col 2 equals: " << zero_two + one_two + two_two << endl;

cout << "\n";

//Adding up tL-bR diagonal (dia 1):
dia1 = addnums(zero_zero,one_one,two_two);
cout << "The sum of dia 1 equals: " << zero_zero + one_one + two_two << endl;

//Adding up bL-tR diagonal (dia 2):
dia2 = addnums(two_zero,one_one,zero_two);
cout << "The sum of dia 2 equals: " << zero_two + one_one + two_zero << endl;

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Equality operator doesn't work in C and C++ the way you think it does.

It is evaluated from left to right, therefore `a == b == c` becomes `(a == b) == c`, or `(true/false) == c`.

The correct way to solve this is to compare each value individually:

```
int sum = row0;
if (row1 == sum && row2 == sum && ...) { ... }
```

#### Update:

You can create your own multiple value comparator like this:

```
template <class Arg, class... Args>
bool all_equal(Arg&& arg, Args&&... args) {
   static_assert(sizeof...(args), "At least 2 arguments expected");
   return (arg == args && ...);
}

// Example
if (all_equal(row0, row1, ...)) {}
```

Comment: Thank you Remy for editing my post! I'm not sure what's more elusive and challenging?  C++, or posting a correctly formatted question on stackoverflow!

Comment: Gill, I'll try your suggestion.  Thank you!

Comment: Gil, I tried your suggestion with no change in the outcome.  Could it be that the magic square is just that elusive?  I tried reducing the number range (1-9) in hopes that it would reduce the number of potential combinations, but so far that hasn't helped either.

Comment: @Troy When you write `int sum = row0;`, `row0` is uninitialized, causing undefined behavior. Try putting this assignment right before the `if` condition.

Comment: Still no change.  The program keeps running on indefinitely.  I'm not sure if it's just churning through all the potential combination of numbers, with the conditional statement always coming up false, or whether the conditional statement is somehow not working.  Any added input from anyone would be much appreciated!

Comment: Gill, I know YOU can surely figure this out with your own version of the program, but I'm not looking for a complete rewrite of my program, but just for someone (like you) to tell me what's wrong with mine.  In the meantime, I really appreciate the time you've taken to help me!